# Integration of Tsiolkovsky rocket equation with gravity

Tags: integration, derivatives, mathematical-astronomy

I have been looking for some time now at how to integrate correctly Tsiolkovsky's rocket equation with gravity applied. Though some articles and forums (including stack Exchange) provide a close solution to this problem, none seem to integrate the specific version of the equation that I am looking for.

I was able to integrate the gravity and `dv` pretty easily from `t0` to `tf` (or from the start of the experiment, till its end.) It's the logarithm though that I cannot figure out, should I integrate it from `M0` to `Mf` ? (or from the initial mass at `t0` till the final mass at `tf`.) And if so, how would I do that?

Overall, I am looking for a numerical expression for `dx` or the velocity's derivative from this equation.

Tsiolkovsky's rocket equation:
    $\frac{dv}{dt} = u*ln(\frac{m0}{mf}) - g*t$

where `u` is the exhaust velocity, `m0` and `mf` are the initial and final masses respectivly, `g` is standard gravity and `t` is time.

For my usage, the initial and final masses can be assumed to be constants, because I calculate them beforehand using a different expression and they do not change.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to derive the Tsiolkovsky equation from basic principles and integration, or are you starting with the equation and trying to integrate it to obtain a velocity function/position function?

Comment: I am starting with the existing equation, and trying to obtain the 'dx' expression. @MarkB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tsiolkovsky's rocket equation

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = av - gt$$

with

$$a=\ln\left(\frac{m0}{mf}\right)$$

Let $y=ve^{-at}$, take the derivative of $y$,

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -gte^{-at}$$

Then, integrate-by-parts,

$$y=-g\int te^{-at} = \frac{g}{a}te^{-at}+\frac{g}{a^2}e^{-at}+C$$

In terms of original variable $v$,

$$v(t)=\frac{g}{a}t+\frac{g}{a^2}+Ce^{at}$$

Comment: Thanks! this is great. Using a computer program I was able to map out the equation and graph it, it looks like the correct solution. Also, I didn't know you can pull out the log and integrate without it - this makes it so much easier! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad could help